# Scan in array of Nested Objects - DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries, dynamoose

So, i am trying to filter objects inside of an array using dynamo db.
This is my sample object

```
client: {
 "name":"etc"
 "subscriptions": [
   {
     "status": "canceled"
     ... other fields
   },
   {
     "status": "active"
     ... other fields 
   }
 ]
}
```

I am using filter expressions and dynamoose scan method, what i want to achieve in this case would be the scan bring me back all subscriptions that have the canceled status, is this possible using dynamodb and this kind of objects?.

```
var filter = {
        FilterExpression: "#subscriptions.#status = :statusValue",
        ExpressionAttributeNames: {
          "#subscriptions":"subscriptions",
          "#status": "status"
        },
        ExpressionAttributeValues:{
          ":statusValue": "canceled"
        }
 };

dynamooseEntity.scan(filter).exec();
```